# How to add a box-shadow on a parent when child radio is checked?

Tags: html, css

I need that when the radio is checked on a div it shows a box-shadow.
Here's the code

```html
        <div className="check-block">
          <div className="check">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="internet"
              value="residencial"
            />
            <label for="residencial">Internet Residencial</label>
          </div>
          <div className="check">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="internet"
              value="empresarial"
            />
            <label for="empresarial">Internet Empresarial</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You tagged this with React, are you looking for a React based solution?

Comment: What css do you already have?

Comment: Here's a React solution: https://jsfiddle.net/89njev4m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the duo `position:relative` *(on the parent)*  and `absolute` on a pseudo from a child to fake the `box-shadow`.

**There is no parent selector if this is what you look for.**

```css
[class="check"]
/* to make the snippet works*/,[className="check"]
/* */{
  position: relative;
}
input:checked + label:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
box-shadow:0 0 3px;
pointer-events:none; /* makes it invisible to the mouse, you can click through the area where it stands */
}
```

```html
<div className="check-block">
  <div className="check">
    <input type="radio" name="internet" value="residencial" />
    <label for="residencial">Internet Residencial</label>
  </div>
  <div className="check">
    <input type="radio" name="internet" value="empresarial" />
    <label for="empresarial">Internet Empresarial</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: result]

Comment: The downside is that you can't click a label to select an option, which is bad UX

Comment: @ChrisG , pointer-events is then required too ;) , i'll update the snippet for that peticular case .

Comment: I guess you can use the label's `for`, but then you have add `id`s to the inputs.

Comment: @ChrisG no id is required, the **+** selector does the job here , run the snippet to find out by yourself ;) If there is more than one element, you can use the ~ selector and select the las label or any other box than can generate a pseudo .

Comment: I did, and clicking the labels does nothing ;)

Comment: @ChrisG okay, which browser do you use here ? because that works for more than a decade

Comment: Latest Chrome and Firefox; to clarify: I'm not talking about the shadows, I'm talking about being able to click the labels to select an option. This has nothing to do with the question really, however a simple solution is to move the input inside the label, which would kill your solution. The alternative is to connect the labels to the inputs, which works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ckv13juf/

Comment: Looks like we're massively talking past each other, I really don't mean to be rude or anything, sorry. I didn't miss any update, I'm running your current snippet on Firefox, and clicking on "Internet Residencial" does not select the radio button for me, are you saying this works for you? To be clear, I'm talking about clicking the **text**, not the radio button circle.

Comment: @ChrisG i misunderstood you, it was a copy/paste from op's code and label/input are indeed missing attributes id/for to work together ;)